# 2-Legged oAuth Upload to Google Docs Failing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oauth, google-data-api

I am a Google Apps user trying to write a function in VB.NET to upload files to specific user's Google Docs accounts (all within my Google Apps domain of course). I have attempted this with the Google GData API for ASP.NET but unfortunately, according to a Googler, this library does not add a xoauth_requestor_id to the url...

I don't know how to add this though and have no idea how to construct the HTTP POST request manually, especially with regards to how to send the XML payload that Google mentions on its site shown below...

Below is my attempt to construct a HTTP POST to Google Docs manually using code found at: [Google GData API page](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html#tokensGADomains)

This code is returning a 401-Unauthorized error:

```
Protected Sub UploadToGDocs2() 
        Dim str As String = "" 
        'The commented-out code below is the HTTP POST code mentioned on 
        'http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html#tokensGADomains 
        ' 
        'POST /feeds/documents/private/full?xoauth_requestor_id=j.doe%40example.com HTTP1.1 
        'Host:   docs.google.com() 
        'Content-Type: application/atom+xml 
        'Authorization: OAuth() 
        'oauth_version="1.0", 
        'oauth_nonce="1c4fbbe4387a685829d5938a3d97988c", 
        'oauth_timestamp="1227303732", 
        'oauth_consumer_key="example.com", 
        'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
        '        oauth_signature = "lqz%2F%2BfwtusOas8szdYd0lAxC8%3D" 
        '<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"> 
        '  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" 
        '                 term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#document" /> 
        '  <atom:title>Company Perks</atom:title> 
        '</atom:entry 

       'Here's my attempt to build the HTTP POST command in .NET 
        Dim web As New System.Net.WebClient() 
        web.Headers.Add("Host", "docs.google.com") 
        web.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml") 
        web.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth") 
        Dim keyval As New StringBuilder 
        keyval.Append("oauth_version=1.0") 
        keyval.Append("&oauth_nonce=1c4fbbe4387a685829d5938a3d97988c") 
        keyval.Append("&oauth_timestamp=1227303732") 
        keyval.Append("&oauth_consumer_key=myDomain.com") 
        keyval.Append("&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1") 
        keyval.Append("&oauth_signature=mySecretKey") 



       'I have no idea what to do with the XML code below. Where does it go? 

        keyval.Append("&<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/ 
Atom'>") 
        keyval.Append("<atom:category scheme='http:// 
schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'") 
        keyval.Append("term='http://schemas.google.com/docs/ 
2007#document'") 
        keyval.Append("<atom:title>Company Perks</atom:title>") 
        keyval.Append("</atom:entry") 
        Dim d As Byte() = 
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyval.ToString) 
        Dim myUrl As String = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/someone 
%40myDomain.com/private/full?xoauth_requestor_id=someone 
%40myDomain.com" 
        Dim res As Byte() = web.UploadData(myUrl.ToString, "POST", d) 
        Response.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(res)) 
    End Sub
```